# Android's strings.xml giving a nullpointer on retrieval.

Tags: android

Perhaps one of you great gods/goddesses of Android may see it fit to help a mere peasent as myself.

If I use

```
String myNewAppId = "34";
```

I am good.
If I use

```
String myNewAppId = this.getString(R.string.appid);
```

or

```
String myNewAppId = getResources.getString(R.string.appid);
```

setting my strings.xml file to

```
<string name="appid">34</string>
```

I show no errors yet I crash with a nullpointerException.

Comment: are you using the latest SDK?

Comment: yes just went to the new eclipse and updated my android and google sdk/apis  last week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes Eclipse does not update the string resource. Try cleaning and rebuilding your project manually to force it to be updated.

Comment: hmmm Nope that did not work. And to check I set the text on a button on my layout to "@string/appid" and I got the correct string. :(

Comment: Your code above is correct. So it's either something wrong elsewhere in the code or a problem with Eclipse (I'd bet the latter). Are you sure the exception is on the getString line? Also, try cleaning the project, closing the project, closing Eclipse, uninstalling the app from your emulator or device and then re-opening everything. That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: press `Ctrl+Shift+S` to save all files then rocks :D